# Hashmap only saving the last item

Tags: java, android

I'm getting multiple values from an ArrayList and saving them in a variable:

**For each code:**

```
 static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> test = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (RoomHandler roomHandler : roomHandlerArrayList) {

        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();

        item.put(ROOM_ID, Integer.toString(roomHandler.getRoomID()));

        item.put(ROOM_NAME, roomHandler.getRoomName());

        test.add(item);

    }
```

And I'm calling these variables on my adapter. But when I try to print both variables, I only get the ROOM_NAME variable, when I print the ROOM_ID, I get the ROOM_NAME value, which it means that the last value is being recorded twice.

**Adapter code:**

```
String getRoomName = (String) ((Map) getItem(position))
        .get(RoomsActivity.ROOM_NAME);

String getRoomID = (String) ((Map) getItem(position))
        .get(RoomsActivity.ROOM_ID);

roomName.setText(getRoomName + getRoomID); //prints ROOM_NAME + ROOM_NAME
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the values of `ROOM_NAME` and `ROOM_ID`?

Comment: The values from the ROOM_NAME and ROOM_ID are the values that I am getting from my database table. I just initialized these variables to record those values later.

Comment: And their values are...?

Comment: The values from the first record are ID 1, and ROOM_NAME test1, and to the second record the ID is 2, and the ROOM_NAME is test2.

Comment: I mean the constants, `ROOM_NAME` and `ROOM_ID`, the values you're using for hash keys.

Comment: Ow I'm really dumb, thank you so much, I didn't use hash keys, now is working fine. thanks.

Comment: Well, you used hash keys, otherwise you couldn't have put anything in the hash.